# How to change color of menu highlight in my site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

My site currently has got red color for highlighting the menu on mouse over and black color by default. Please see my [website here](http://znerim.com/). Is it possible to change this color so that it can be matched with the logo. i.e light blue on mouse over and dark green as default. Can it be done using custom css code? (I have used the theme Awaken)

Thanks!

Comment: Ask the question [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Sure, from next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can change it with this css.

```
.main-navigation {
    background: #ADD8E6;
    color: #000;
}
.main-navigation a:hover {
  background: darkgreen;
}
```

And for current tab use this selector

```
.main-navigation li.current-menu-item {
   background: pink;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you.
The hover color is now corrected with the code: 
.main-navigation a:hover {
  background: #00bfff;
}
Now I need to change the background color of "home", "trending posts", "search engine optimization", "Social Media", etc. Is that possible?

On giving the first code,i.e.
.main-navigation a {
    background: #ADD8E6;
    color: #000;
}
only half of the menu background get that color.

Comment: I edited my answer. use .main-navigation selector. Don't forget to mark it as correct if it was correct.

Comment: But the home still has the red color as default! 
Also if possible please tell me how to change the background color of all other titles, "Trending posts", "search engine optimization", etc.

Comment: Yes because that wasn't part of your initial question. I edited my comment.

Comment: Please see now.. the main menu is solved. Thanks for that, but the other titles didn't get that color! Only the home at top left and bottom left got that.   On giving the last command, it said element is overqualified, just use .current-menu-item without element name.